# UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL for Telephone

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I am just trying to make phone call like this. However, I can't call for second phone number. When I call, I got this error. May I know what is wrong?

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```
        let phone = "tel://1818,,,1,,,344#,,,959533788" //This one ok
        let phone = "tel://18005333333,,,1#,,,421#,,,959533788" //This one not okay

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone)!;
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url);
```

Comment: do you need the pound sing "#" to be dialed?

Comment: Yes. I need # because I am calling to use phone card.